# Untracked files in git while checkout

Tags: git

When I try to checkout to my bryan branch from my master branch, I get this message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Manager/InvoicingAdslManager.php
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

If I remove this untracked file, does it disappear from my bryan branch?

Would be awesome if annyone could explain.

Comment: Yes, since it's not under git. Stash it if you want to save this.

Comment: While http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630693/git-warning-of-file-overwriting-due-to-supposedly-untracked-files talks about "pull", the problem is essentially the same; see those answers for some hints.

Comment: You don't need neither to Stash them nor to pull (the same). The only thing you need is to commit your changes. So, they will be stored in your local **bryan** branch. After that you will be able to checkout another branch. But if you will revert your changes without committing them - you will loose them.

Comment: @WhiteAngel The OP may not want to put the untracked file (back) under version control. I don't think committing is appropriate, here.

Comment: @Jubobs, I'm not sure that I got you. Noone was talking about "untracked" files at all. Git is saying that there was modification in "tracked" file and that's why he cannot switch to another branch without committing changes or resolving this issue in any other way (reverting changes)

Comment: @WhiteAngel The error message explicitly refers to *untracked* files: `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout`. It seems that the file(s) in question used to be tracked, but no longer are, and if the checkout were carried out, the version sitting in the working tree would be lost. Stashing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

With out commit, if you switch to other branch you will this error.

- first check on which branch you are on by using `git branch` command. If you are in master branch then do commit.
- If you are not in master branch then move to master branch then do commit.
- if you donot want to track that file use this command `git rm --cached filename`